# Drop into interactive console for a running Play app

Tags: scala, playframework

In Play, I can start an interactive console, and then start the application within it, as below:

```
[app] $ console

scala> new play.core.StaticApplication(new java.io.File("."))
```

Is it similarly possible to drop into an interactive console for an already running Play application? Is there an SBT task in the wild that can do this?

Comment: Just to be clear, two questions: 1. This is a complete Play application directory, not the `target` directory from `play dist` or something, right? Because in the latter case, this won't work. 2. If you can start a console with _an instance_ of your Play application (which you should be able to do like this), would that make a difference? Ideally, the application should be stateless. Every service that you could call should be able to connect from a different instance of the application. This is mostly curiosity, but could you add some details for your case?

Comment: just open another console from a different terminal session?

Comment: @Carsten, 1. Yes. 2. What you say makes sense, however, I imagine, such an ability might be useful once in a while.

Comment: @Ashalynd, and how do we connect to the already running application? It doesn't work that way by default (I tested).

Comment: I thought you just meant having the console which has access to your app classes. If by "connecting" you mean something like a runtime hook, then I am not sure if that's possible.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible, but it's an interesting idea! How about creating an issue on Github with your suggestion?

Comment: This might be of interest - https://github.com/xitrum-framework/scalive

Comment: @RichDougherty, I am sorry I missed your comment earlier. Probably could do that, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question fully, such as what are you wanting to do while the application is running? However, If I wanted to use the interactive console while a play application was running, I would use the console within the IDE and use a separate terminal/console to run the application. Hope this helps.